# Temporary alternative --config for curent bash session

Tags: bash

I need to use two different versions of some program in Linux. I can switch between two program versions via `alternatives --config "program-name"`. So my question is how I cat do this command for current bash session locally without changing global system settings?

I think it kinda `chroot` command.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be sufficient, but you could add

```
alternatives --auto program-name
```

to your `.bash_logout` file. Then use `alternatives --config program-name`. This would make it a global change, but return it to its previous state when you log out.